# Change event colour in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am trying to colour events. It gets the colour from the api. I have attempt to do this but no matter how I try to implement it, I can not get it to work.

Here's my two attempts at making it work via different approaches.

1)

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
                events: "/app/calendar/cal/",
                eventClick: function(event) {
                    window.top.location = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/calendar/event/" + event.id;

                },
                eventRender: function(event, element) {
                    $(element).tooltip({title: event.body});
                    $('.fc-content').css("background-color", "red");
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
```

2)

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
                events: "/calendars/cal/",
                url: 'http://google.com/',
                eventClick: function(event) {
                    window.top.location = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/calendars/event/" + event.id;

                },
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                eventRender: function(event, element) {
                      $(element).tooltip({title: event.body});
                  }
            })
        })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eventColor` property of `full calendar`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/er_sarjan/h9cC6/2309/) for same color property for all events.

For more details check : http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
                events: "/app/calendar/cal/",
                eventClick: function(event) {
                    window.top.location = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/calendar/event/" + event.id;

                },
                eventColor: '#378006',
                eventRender: function(event, element) {
                    $(element).tooltip({title: event.body});
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
```

For setting **individual color** of event, add `backgroundColor` property in object of event array.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/er_sarjan/h9cC6/2310/) for individual color.

```
var events_array = [{
        title: 'Test1',
        start: new Date(2015, 09, 14),
        tip: 'Personal tip 1',
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    }, {
        title: 'Test2',
        start: new Date(2015, 09, 15),
        tip: 'Personal tip 2',
        backgroundColor: 'green'
    }];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That was the first way I tried but for some reason it does not work. I have edited my question to include it

Answer (score 1):

You can specify eventColor: '#yourColor', no need to do it in render event.

If you want to change the color for individual events:http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/#color-options